# Outlook Web Access 'broken' - authenticates but displays incorrectly and isn't useable

Tags: iis, exchange-server, outlook-web-app

We have an SBS 2008 server running Exchange. We have 5 users running from an office locally connected to exchange and everything is working perfectly fine. One of our users can begun travelling extensively and would like a way to access his email from any remote machine - Outlook Web Access seems to make sense.

Unfortunately, I've been unable to get it working at all. Our users can connect to our remote domain and login successfully, they can connect to our sharepoint site and can connect remotely to computers on the local network - however Outlook Web Access fails to work correctly.

Upon selecting OWA, the user is presented with a 'broken' version of their inbox. They can see the titles of all the emails they've recently received and so on, but they cannot click on anything or interact with the interface in any way. I cannot possibly understand why this isn't working - it is definitely authenticating and connecting to exchange succesfully but it just doesnt allow any interaction. (Ive attached an image below). I literally have no idea how to proceed with this issue but it's rather important as my user needs access to his email.

I'm (perhaps obviously) not an experienced systems admin, so I apologise if I have not described the issue correctly or if the solution is somewhat obvious.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/duMNo.png

Answer (score 0):

This is now rectified, apologies.

I'll post the solution here just incase anyone else has this issue.

It seems an update to OWA actually ended up breaking it - It installed a new themes and scripts folder into the OWA directory on the server and but didn't populate them with all of the necessary files. I located a backup of the old scripts and theme files and simply copied them into the relevant folders in the updated theme and script folders and it now appears to be all be working correctly.